# How to launch a second window in applicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to launch a debug log window when my application opens. Here is how I planned to do this:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    LogWindowController *lwc = [[LogWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"LogWindow"];
    [lwc showWindow:self];
    [[lwc logWindow] orderFront:self];
}
```

The log window is created and operating, available in the Window menu for example. But it's not visible anywhere.

If I run the same code in response to a menu item, the log window shows as expected.

Why is this happening, and how can I open my log window visible on application launch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing holding a strong reference to this window controller. At the end of this function, `lwc` will be released, which will immediately close the window (before a drawing cycle has occurred, so you won't see a flash or anything).

You need to store `lwc` in a `strong` property so it isn't released until you want it to be.